# How to download raw bytes from web on iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage, download, arrays, afnetworking-2

My iPhone app must download and display a user's profile picture when s/he signs into the app. The problem is: we store the images as raw byte arrays on our server (don't ask me why...  I didn't set up the database, and it's too late to change now).  Does anyone know how to download a byte array (asynchronously) stored at a specific URL, in order to convert it into a UIImage?

To upload/store the original UIImage, I convert to NSData using UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image), and upload that NSData using an AFNetworking 2.0 multi-port http POST request.

Anyone?

Comment: did my answer help? is anything still unclear? @DanMoore

Answer (score 0):

You can just use NSData's initWithContentsOfURL method to download the data, and use GCD to do it asynchronously.

But honestly, the better solution would be to set the 'Content-Type' header on the response from the server to 'image/jpeg'.  It doesn't matter how the image is stored on the server, as long as the response header indicates that it's an image, the client will not know the difference.

It might not even matter - UIImage initWithContentsOfURL might do it for you.